# How to stop a async evaluating function on timeout?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, interrupt

say we have a simple async call we want to kill/terminate/eliminate on timeout

```
// future::wait_for
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <future>         // std::async, std::future
#include <chrono>         // std::chrono::milliseconds

// a non-optimized way of checking for prime numbers:
bool is_prime (int x) {
  for (int i=2; i<x; ++i) if (x%i==0) return false;
  return true;
}

int main ()
{
  // call function asynchronously:
  std::future<bool> fut = std::async (is_prime,700020007); 

  // do something while waiting for function to set future:
  std::cout << "checking, please wait";
  std::chrono::milliseconds span (100);
  while (fut.wait_for(span)==std::future_status::timeout)
    std::cout << '.';

  bool x = fut.get();

  std::cout << "\n700020007 " << (x?"is":"is not") << " prime.\n";

  return 0;
}
```

we want to kill it as soon as first timeout happens. Cant find a method in future.

The closest I could find to stop a running task was  `std::packaged_task` `reset` method yet it does not say if it can interrupt a running task. So how one kills a task running asyncrinusly not using boost thread or other non stl libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to stop a `std::async` out of the box... However, You can do this, pass a `bool` to terminate the `is_prime` method and throw an exception if there is a timeout:

```
// future::wait_for
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <future>         // std::async, std::future
#include <chrono>         // std::chrono::milliseconds  

// A non-optimized way of checking for prime numbers:
bool is_prime(int x, std::atomic_bool & run) {
    for (int i = 2; i < x && run; ++i)
    {
        if (x%i == 0) return false;
    }

    if (!run)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("timed out!");
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    // Call function asynchronously:
    std::atomic_bool run;
    run = true;
    std::future<bool> fut = std::async(is_prime, 700020007, std::ref(run));

    // Do something while waiting for function to set future:
    std::cout << "checking, please wait";
    std::chrono::milliseconds span(100);
    while (fut.wait_for(span) == std::future_status::timeout)
    {
        std::cout << '.';
        run = false;
    }

    try
    {
        bool x = fut.get();
        std::cout << "\n700020007 " << (x ? "is" : "is not") << " prime.\n";
    }
    catch (const std::runtime_error & ex)
    {
        // Handle timeout here
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### Why being able to stop thread is bad.

Stopping threads at an arbitrary point is dangerous and will lead to resource leaks, where resources being pointers, handles to files and folders, and other things the program should do.

When killing a thread, the thread may or may not be doing work. Whatever it was doing, it won’t get to complete and any variables successfully created will not get their destructors called because there is no thread to run them on.

[I have outlined some of the issues here.](http://studiofreya.com/2015/07/05/how-to-stop-a-std-async-task/)

Answer (score 0):

I think its not possible to safely interrupt running cycle from outside of cycle itself, so STL doesn't provide such a functionality. Of course, one could try to kill running thread, but it's not safe as may lead to resource leaking.

You can check for timeout inside `is_prime` function and return from it if timeout happens. Or you can try to pass a reference to `std::atomic<bool>` to `is_prime` and check its value each iteration. Then, when timeout happens you change the value of the atomic in the `main` so `is_prime` returns.